# TimePicker Dialog's updateTime doesnt have any effect

Tags: android, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have a custom implementation of TimePickerDialog and within that I override onTimeChanged method do some altercations of my choice. I saw some  posts asking to use reflection to get the TimePicker of this dialog and set onTimeChange listner to "this", why do we even need to do this..I mean the actual time picker code itself sets the  timeChangeListner to "this"

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/android/app/TimePickerDialog.java

should not we just override the onTimeChanged Method? but the thing is that even though the onTimeChanged gets called, its called multiple times and updateTime doesnt seem to have any effect as such on the timepicker.
 following is the implementation of TimePickerDialog :

```
public class RangeTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog{

    private Integer minHour, minMinute, maxHour, maxMinute;

    public RangeTimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener listener, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {
        super(context, listener, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
        try {
            Class<?> superclass = getClass().getSuperclass();
            Field mTimePickerField = superclass.getDeclaredField("mTimePicker");
            mTimePickerField.setAccessible(true);
            TimePicker mTimePicker = (TimePicker) mTimePickerField.get(this);
            mTimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        }
    }


    public void setMinTime(int hour, int minute) {
        minHour = hour;
        minMinute = minute;
    }

    public void setMaxTime(int hour, int min) {
        maxHour = hour;
        maxMinute = min;
    }


    private void updateDisplay() {
        setTitle("Please Select A Valid Time");
    }
    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Log.d("RangeTimePicker", "onTimeChanged Called");
        if (minHour != null) {

            if (hourOfDay < minHour || (hourOfDay == minHour && minute <= minMinute)) {
                updateTime(minHour, minMinute);
                updateDisplay();
            }
        }
        if( maxHour != null) {

            if(hourOfDay > maxHour || (hourOfDay ==maxHour && minute > maxMinute)){
                updateTime(maxHour, maxMinute);
                updateDisplay();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put a breakpoint and see if minHour and MaxHour are not always null when it enters onTimeChanged

Comment: sorry..it does get called just that update time method doesnt seem to have any effect on the time picker's behavior..i tried replacing the params of updateTime() with minHour and minMinute ..though the selected values still remain to the one user actually selected

Comment: @RgDixit did you ever figure this out?  I'm still seeing no effect of updateTIme.